# Can’t get a Middleman blog article summary?

Tags: blogs, middleman

This works fine:

`<% blog.articles.each_with_index do |article, i| %>
  <h2><%= link_to article.title, article %> <span><%= article.date.strftime('%b %e') %></span></h2>
  <%= article.body %>
<% end %>`

This does not:

`<% blog.articles.each_with_index do |article, i| %>
  <h2><%= link_to article.title, article %> <span><%= article.date.strftime('%b %e') %></span></h2>
  <%= article.summary %>
<% end %>`

Something about that summary throws an error:

`` TypeError: type mismatch: String given
    /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/middleman-blog-4.0.0/lib/middleman-blog/blog_article.rb:110:in `=~'
    /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/middleman-blog-4.0.0/lib/middleman-blog/blog_article.rb:110:in `default_summary_generator'
    /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/middleman-blog-4.0.0/lib/middleman-blog/blog_article.rb:98:in `summary'
    /Users/bob/Dropbox/Web Development/Projects/Middleman/BRP/source/index.html.erb:11:in `block (2 levels) in singleton class' ``

and so on...

Here's the part of my config.rb concerning the blog gem:

`activate :blog do |blog|
  # This will add a prefix to all links, template references and source paths
  # blog.prefix = "blog"
  # blog.permalink = "{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}.html"
  # Matcher for blog source files
  blog.sources = "posts/{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html"
  # blog.taglink = "tags/{tag}.html"
  # blog.layout = "layout"
  blog.summary_separator = "==="
  blog.summary_length = 250
  # blog.year_link = "{year}.html"
  # blog.month_link = "{year}/{month}.html"
  # blog.day_link = "{year}/{month}/{day}.html"
  # blog.default_extension = ".markdown"
  blog.tag_template = "tag.html"
  blog.calendar_template = "calendar.html"
  # Enable pagination
  blog.paginate = true
  blog.per_page = 10
  blog.page_link = "page/{num}"
  end
  # activate :directory_indexes`

And my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

## Middleman Gems

gem "middleman", "~> 4.1.0"
gem "middleman-blog"
gem "middleman-livereload"
gem 'middleman-autoprefixer'

## gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.3'

## For feed.xml.builder

gem "builder", "~> 3.0"
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but `blog.summary_separator = "==="` looks like a troublemaker.

Try another string that couldn't be incorrectly interpreted as a comparison operator and see if it works.

Maybe try `blog.summary_separator = /(READMORE)/`

Don't forget to make that change in your post files as well. (Forgetting that sort of stuff is what makes me chase my tail more often than not.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to uncomment the two lines in config.rb:

`blog.summary_separator = "==="`

`blog.summary_length = 250`

Try adding this line below 
`<%= article.summary %>`

`<%= link_to 'Read more…', article %>`